# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 at beerregister.BeerRegister.list(BeerRegister.java:66)

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

My Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at beerregister.BeerRegister.list(BeerRegister.java:66)
```

How can I fix it?

My code is a bit ugly, sorry.

```
package beerregister;

import java.util.*;
import beerregister.BeerRegister.NameComparator;

public class BeerRegister{

public String name;
public String style;
public String alc;

List<BeerRegister> bb = new ArrayList<BeerRegister>();

int szamlalo = 0;
//private StyleComparator sc;
//private AlcComparator ac;

public BeerRegister(){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cmd[];
    System.out.println("Lökjed:");
    while(true){
        cmd = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
        if(cmd[0].equals("add")) {add(cmd[1],cmd[2],cmd[3]);}
        if(cmd[0].equals("list")) {list(cmd);}
    }
}
public BeerRegister(String name, String style, String alc){
    this.name=name;
    this.style=style;
    this.alc=alc;
}

public void add(String name,String style,String alc){
    BeerRegister br = new BeerRegister(name, style, alc);
//      br.name = name;
//      br.style = style;
//      br.alc = alc;
    bb.add(br);
}

public void list(String[] cmd){

    System.out.println(bb.size());
    //synchronized(bb){}
    if(cmd[1].equals("name")) 
        Collections.sort(bb,new NameComparator());
    //if(cmd[1].equals("style")) StyleComparator();
    //if(cmd[1].equals("alc")) AlcComparator();

  for(int i = 0; i < bb.size();i++){
    System.out.println(bb.get(i).name+ " "+ bb.get(i).style + " " + bb.get(i).alc);

  }
}

class NameComparator implements Comparator<BeerRegister>{
    @Override
    public int compare(BeerRegister a, BeerRegister b) {
        return a.name.compareToIgnoreCase(b.name);
    }
}
public static void main( String [] args){
    BeerRegister xyz = new BeerRegister();
}
}
```

so how can i fiy my problem? please help.

Comment: Which line is `BeerRegister.java:66`?

Comment: What was the input given to this program?  `List`?  `List name`?  Something else?

Comment: The stack trace contains the exact line at which the exception is thrown. And the javadoc explains what this exception means and when it's thrown. Have you read them? Hint: if an array is of length 0, you can't access its element at index 1, because it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem add some conditions in `BeerRegister` method, like this:

```
        if (cmd.length > 3 && cmd[0].equals("add")) {
            add(cmd[1], cmd[2], cmd[3]);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Rewrite CMD Please!");
        }
        if (cmd.length > 1 && cmd[0].equals("list")) {
            list(cmd);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is the only line from where the error can come...

```
if(cmd[1].equals("name"))
```

Please debug, and take a look at what the case is...

The possible cause is that cmd is just a simple `list`, and nothing follows... To properlz operate the counter, you have to input `list name`...

To correct, check for length of the array before accessing its elements

```
if(cmd.length>2 && cmd[1].equals("name"))  {
    Collections.sort(bb,new NameComparator()); 
}
```

Always use braces!!!

(this is subjective: I'd stick with English names... Especially half English-half Hungarian was very frustrating to work with, even worse than using fully localized names. Either `szamlalo` or `BeerRegister` should go...)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your inserting information correctly. You need to check that `cmd = sc.nextLine().split(" ");` will make `cmd` array to have larger size then `1`

```
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String cmd[];
    System.out.println("Lökjed:");
    while(true){
        cmd = sc.nextLine().split(" ");

        if(cmd[0].equals("add")) {add(cmd[1],cmd[2],cmd[3]);}
        if(cmd[0].equals("list")) {list(cmd);}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the length of your cmd array before gettimg index 3.